# Eclipse plugin development: How to avoid deprecated ActionSet?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

From an official Eclipse plugin development tutorial, I copied the following code to define a new button in my plugin.xml

```
<extension point = "org.eclipse.ui.actionSets">
        <actionSet
            id="org.eclipse.examples.helloworld.HelloWorldActionSet"
            label="Hello World"
        visible="true"
        description="The action set for the Eclipse Hello World example">
        <menu
        id="org.eclipse.examples.helloworld.HelloWorldMenu"
        label="Samples">
        <separator name="samples"/>
        </menu>
        <action id="org.eclipse.examples.helloworld.actions.HelloWorldAction"
        menubarPath="org.eclipse.examples.helloworld.HelloWorldMenu/samples"
        toolbarPath="Normal"            
        label="Hello World"
        tooltip="Press to see a message"
        icon="icons/helloworld.gif"
        class="org.eclipse.examples.helloworld.HelloWorldAction"/>
        </actionSet>
    </extension>
```

But unfortunately, I get some deprecated warnings. Especiall for the extension point and the actionset. I couldn't find any information how to avoid that. Any hints?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the whole action framework is deprecated. Nowadays, one uses commands instead. You can find more information  about commands for instance [eclipse-tips.com](http://blog.eclipse-tips.com/2009/01/commands-part-1-actions-vs-commands.html) or [vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCommands/article.html).