# Adding a menu to a context menu

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to figure out how to add a menu to a context, or popup menu in Eclipse. I can add an item, but I can't find anything about adding a submenu.

I've tried this in the plugin.xml

```
<extension
     id="add.item"
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">         

  <menuContribution            
        locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer">
        <menu
             id="com.xiledsystems.altBridge.menu"
             label="AltBridge Tools">
        </menu>

      </menuContribution>

<menuContribution
     locationURI= "menu:com.xiledsystems.altBridge.menu">
    <command
        commandId="com.xiledsystems.altbridge.sample"
        label="Sample Try (AltBridge)">
    </command>
</menuContribution>
```

This doesn't do anything it seems. No submenu comes up.

The reason is, I have a few different things going in the popup menu, and I want to consolidate them all into one submenu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add actions to the menu.

```
<action
    class="ActionDelegate"
    icon="icons/sample.gif"
    id="ActionID"
    label="Action"
    menubarPath="com.xiledsystems.altBridge.menu/content"
    style="push" />
```

This will add an action under `com.xiledsystems.altBridge.menu` menu with label `Action`. `class` specifies a class which implements the action.

I'd recommend you read some book about Eclipse development, for example [Eclipse Plugins](http://www.qualityeclipse.com/eclipse-plugins). It's not free, but there are free samples with sources, so you can install it in your Eclipse and take a look.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work with your suggestion. Is there an "updated" way of doing this? I get a warning on the left saying that Element 'action' is deprecated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538288/eclipse-plugin-development-how-to-avoid-deprecated-actionset

Comment: The above link is basically just a short answer saying: _"the whole action framework is deprecated. Nowadays, one uses commands instead."_ and linking to two tutorials on commands: http://blog.eclipse-tips.com/2009/01/commands-part-1-actions-vs-commands.html and http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommands/article.html